# Eclipse - How to cancel Automatic Alignments at Android's GUI?

Tags: android, eclipse, user-interface, sdk, alignment

I'm programming an Android application with Eclipse using Android's SDK, and I have a serious problem with the GUI Editor.

The problem is auto-alignment: For example, I drag and drop one button into the GUI Form.

And then I drag another button, which HAS to align to something, usually it aligns to the first button, but also if not, it has to align to something else.

And that means, if I move the first button, the second button moves as well.

This is seriously bad because every time I drag one button, it drags all the others away.

Is there a way to cancel this thing? What I mean is that I'll be able to freely drag around Buttons in the form, without having them align to other Buttons and moving with them.

I come from .NET development, where in Visual Studio for example, this kind of auto alignment just doesn't exist, which is perfect. You can freely drag buttons all over without having them align or stick to each other.

So can I force the buttons not to align, just like in Visual Studio GUI design, for example?

Comment: The fact is that Android development is different because of all the different screen sizes you develop for.  I doubt most developers even drag and drop controls beyond adding them to the layout.  If you want detailed control of your Views once they've been added, you should use the XML editor or modify the different properties in the WYSIWYG editor, as opposed to dragging and dropping.

Comment: check here for common layouts and examples http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html